# Show $\vdash (\forall y_1)\dotsc (\forall y_n)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I would like to show that $\vdash (\forall y_1)\dotsc (\forall y_n)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a wf. When I see this, I thought I need to use induction. But I can't seem to do it. Here is my attempt.

Case $n = 1$ is true because there is an axiom (call it (A4)) that I have learnt, which states that
$$(\forall x_i)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B} $$

For $n = 2$, we have the following:
\begin{align}
 1. &\ (\forall y_1)(\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{Hypothesis}\\
 2. &\ (\forall y_1)(\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow (\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \ \text{(A4)}\\
 3. &\ (\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{Modus ponens, 1,2}\\
 4. &\ (\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B} \ \ \ \ \text{(A4)}\\
 5. &\ \mathcal{B} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{Modus ponens, 3, 4}
\end{align}
Step 1- 5 shows that $(\forall y_1)(\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \vdash \mathcal{B}$. The wf $(\forall y_1)(\forall y_2)\mathcal{B}$ does not contain any free variable and we do not apply any generalization in the deduction, so by the deduction theorem, $\vdash (\forall y_1)(\forall y_2)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}.$

And lastly, here is the part where I get stuck. As for the induction hypothesis, let now $n = k$ and assume that
$$\vdash (\forall y_1)\dotsc (\forall y_k)\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}.$$
I need to show show that $\vdash (\forall y_1)\dotsc (\forall y_k)(\forall y_{k+1})\mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}.$ However, I have no idea how to use this induction hypothesis to show the claim.

Comment: Use example page 72: $(∀y_1) \ldots (∀y_k)(∀y_{k+1}) \mathcal B ⇒ (∀y_{k+1})(∀y_1) \ldots (∀y_k) \mathcal B$. Now you can apply the Induction Hypothesis.

Comment: How do you apply the induction hypothesis ?